# What happens to a global hook when an executable process that hosts it crashes?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hook

Say, if I set up a [global hook procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985(v=vs.85).aspx) in my executable process:

```
//Set global hook
hHook = ::SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, HookWndProc_WH_KEYBOARD_LL,
          ::GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
```

and this process crashes.

What happens to this global hook?

Comment: The hook is removed.

Comment: What makes you think that would be a *global* hook procedure? Global hooks must reside in a `dll`, and GetModuleHandle(NULL) returns an `exe` handle.

Comment: @dxiv: Passing `0x0` (not sure why the OP is using `NULL`) for the *dwThreadId* to `SetWindowsHookEx` makes this a global hook. Low-level keyboard hooks do not need to be implemented in DLLs (see [LowLevelKeyboardProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985.aspx): *"This hook is called in the context of the thread that installed it."*). This hook is implemented through message-sending in contrast to other global hooks, that inject DLLs into the target processes.

Comment: @dxiv: Good explanation on [why low-level hooks aren't injected](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050907-22/?p=34303).

Comment: @IInspectable You are right about the LL hooks, thank you for the correction. FWIW even the MSDN page for [SetWindowsHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx) is wrong on that point: `hMod [in] - Type: HINSTANCE - A handle to the *DLL* containing the hook procedure pointed to by the lpfn parameter.`.

Comment: @dxiv: Why is it wrong? For most global hooks you'd get that `HMODULE` handle by calling `LoadLibrary` on its DLL. So if you want you can also put `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` hook into a DLL as well (if you really wish to complicate your life.) It's just because that this hook is also allowed to reside in the same process, for the reasons explained quite conceitedly by Raymond Chen in the link above, I used `GetModuleHandle(NULL)`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Do you have any links to MSDN page that states that "hooks will be removed" if process crashes or is terminated?

Comment: @c00000fd `Why is it wrong?` Turns out it's not wrong. I was under the (mistaken) impression when I wrote the comment that global hooks were always injected, which would have required the code be in a dll. @IInspectable pointed out the exception in the case of LL hooks, with the relevant background info, so you can safely ignore my first comment at this point.

Comment: I don't think there are any such docs.

Comment: The docs *do* say explicitly that if your hook procedure does not respond within a particular timeout period, the hook will be removed. So that indirectly guarantees that a crashed process's hook will be removed. I don't know why you're looking for official documentation. If you can't write an app that doesn't crash, then you shouldn't be installing hooks. A crash is a *fatal error*, not something you should just rely on the operating system to clean up after.

Comment: @CodyGray: Did you consider that someone can terminate my app via Task Manager or other means, which is analogous to it crashing?

Comment: If there is a malicious or rogue user terminating applications, then you have a bigger problem. Anyway, that is not something you can design for. What are you going to do differently if the answer is "yes" versus if the answer is "no"? You can't stop your app from being terminated, and you don't get a chance to clean up, so you just have to hope that the OS will. Or that someone won't terminate your process, the same assumption all programs make.

Comment: @CodyGray: If the answer was that my crashing process would've affected the system (or user desktop in this case) I would not use this hook for my app. There are too many software developers that haven't asked themselves this very question, that leaves stuff like changed screen timeouts, desktop icons, etc. altered when the app crashes or is terminated. And there's nothing rogue about it. It's a normal development process that most developers need to be asking themselves.

Answer (score 3):

when thread exit - system delete hooks created by this thread (in win32k.FreeThreadsWindowHooks) - so if thread exit, without UnhookWindowsHookEx it will be auto removed whatever. process crashes -> it threads exit -> hooks removed. so nothing worry on system level not be. the worst variant - when thread with HookWndProc_WH_KEYBOARD_LL hang or not call GetMessage/PeekMessage in loop, but not died. in this case every key down event will be delivered with several seconds delay

Comment: Where do you take this info from?

Comment: http://read.pudn.com/downloads3/sourcecode/windows/248345/win2k/private/ntos/w32/ntuser/kernel/hooks.c__.htm + look under Debugger

Comment: crap, the link is dead

Comment: @Dee may be this - https://pastebin.com/PWXQUuJY

Comment: @Dee more functions - [`xxxDestroyThreadInfo`](https://pastebin.com/tzTxvrAY) and [`UserThreadCallout`](https://pastebin.com/rnurGSHN) but this os only cobcrete implementation. anyway kernel cleanup hooks and another thread resources on exit